# switch user (su) hanging

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel, rhel7

So I have a strange issue which I'm pretty sure is SSH based.

If I ssh direct it works fine:

```
ssh user@domain <host>
```

If I then sudo to root this also works fine:

```
sudo su -
```

However If i subsequently su to a user from root it hangs for around 30-60 seconds then times out.

```
su - <user>
```

Eventually it does switch user. Likewise once I've su'd, if i exit my shell and go back up to root it will also hang.

Any ideas? There's nothing in /var/log/secure other than pam authentication messages.

Also I'm not sure whether "su" uses SSH under the hood? but I've noticed that rsync also has the same hanging issues and I do believe rsync DOES use SSH.

Comment: You check .bashrc and .bash_profile files in user's home directory

Comment: What is result for su - root? Does it hang, too? Which disks are used for user's home directory? Maybe can it be nfs?

Comment: If i go to root via sudo su - root then this works fine. This is using Active Directory users on a new domain. Logging in as the AD user is quick and so is using the AD user to root. Any subsequent user switches hang. Also I've checked .bashrc etc. This also occurs on new local users, if i was to do a useradd for example right now, that user would also be affected.

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/513015/su-username-hangs-if-i-added-a-line-in-etc-bashrc) could be related, for me it was because adding a line in the `/etc/bashrc` file

Answer (score 0):

This is down to the AD authentication in PAM sss which was missing a little configuration in

```
/var/lib/sss/pubconf
```

Thanks for the suggestions anyway.